# gnome-terminal has double frame after 21.10 upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, gnome-terminal

I have just upgraded Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10. If I run GNOME Terminal I have two "frames":

- one with just the directory title.
- the second with the directory title, the <kbd>+</kbd> on the left and the find and settings icons on the right.

That second "frame" is all I am used to getting (other than tab bar, if applicable, and the menu bar, if enabled). I'm also used to getting an always present app bar  vertically on the left. Now I'm getting a horizontal one only when I hit the "diamond" key.

This happened on my desktop, while on my laptop, which I have upgraded to 21.10, it works as expected. Below is what the 21.10 laptop shows:

[image: GNOME Terminal on 21.10 on laptop]

While this is what the 21.10 desktop shows:

[image: GNOME Terminal on 21.10 on desktop]

On the desktop I can get rid of the extra bar by using the `dconf-editor` to set false the `org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings` headerbar, and this gives the following result:

[image: GNOME Terminal on 21.10 on desktop without extra bar]

which is what the 18.04 terminals looked like, but that's not what I want. I want the <kbd>+</kbd> in the single header. I don't see any setting in the terminal itself that gets me what the laptop is showing.

Have I missed some master setting? Could someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have the package `gtk3-nocsd` installed on the desktop. That package enables the legacy window decorations on all GTK3 applications that use Client Side decorations. As you see, the result nowadays is not always pretty.

You can remove the package with the command

```
sudo apt remove gtk3-nocsd
```

Comment: I removed the package, and even logged out and in, but still get the version in the second image.

Comment: OK, hopefully an answer that helps will come around.